# Deployment, creating jar file?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, java, eclipse

I want to generate the executable jar file for my application, so i used the export tool in eclipse with the extract required libraries into generated JAR option, but when i run it with command line the EngineInitializer failed(the output error at the end), i'm bootstrapping with this class

```
package Deploy;
import java.io.File;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import java.net.URL;

import java.net.URLClassLoader;

import Interface.SondageOCP;

public class Bootstrapper{

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        bootstrapArcobjectsJar();
        SondageOCP.main(args); 
            //Replace ApplicationName with your application's main class
    }

    public static void bootstrapArcobjectsJar(){
        //Get the ArcGIS Engine runtime, if it is available
        String arcObjectsHome = System.getenv("AGSENGINEJAVA");

        //If the ArcGIS Engine runtime is not available, then we can try ArcGIS Desktop runtime
        if(arcObjectsHome == null){
            arcObjectsHome = System.getenv("AGSDESKTOPJAVA");
        }

        //If no runtime is available, exit application gracefully
        if(arcObjectsHome == null){
            if(System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().indexOf("win") > -1){
                System.err.println("You must have ArcGIS Engine Runtime or ArcGIS Desktop " + 
                        "installed in order to execute this sample.");
                System.err.println("Install one of the products above, then re-run this sample.");
                System.err.println("Exiting execution of this sample...");
                System.exit(0); 
            }else{
                System.err.println("You must have ArcGIS Engine Runtime installed " + 
                        "in order to execute this sample.");
                System.err.println("Install the product above, then re-run this sample.");
                System.err.println("Exiting execution of this sample...");
                System.exit(0); 
            }
        }

        //Obtain the relative path to the arcobjects.jar file
        String jarPath = arcObjectsHome + "java" + File.separator + "lib" +
                         File.separator + "arcobjects.jar";

        //Create a new file
        File jarFile = new File(jarPath);

        //Test for file existence
        if(!jarFile.exists()){
            System.err.println("The arcobjects.jar was not found in the following location: " +
                                                jarFile.getParent());
            System.err.println("Verify that arcobjects.jar can be located in the specified folder.");
            System.err.println("If not present, try uninstalling your ArcGIS software and reinstalling it.");
            System.err.println("Exiting execution of this sample...");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //Helps load classes and resources from a search path of URLs
        URLClassLoader sysloader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        Class<URLClassLoader> sysclass = URLClassLoader.class;

        try{
            Method method = sysclass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(sysloader, new Object[]{jarFile.toURI().toURL()});
        }catch (Throwable throwable){
            throwable.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Could not add arcobjects.jar to system classloader");
            System.err.println("Exiting execution of this sample...");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

and the The main called to open the app window is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    EngineInitializer.initializeVisualBeans();
    dao d=new dao();
    open o=new open();
    Sondage[] s=d.haveBD();
    SondageOCP map = new SondageOCP(s,d);
    o.setVisible(false);
    map.setVisible(true);
    }
```

And finally the output error is :

```
C:\Users\mouad\Desktop\SondageOCP>java -jar SondageOCP.jar
Could not load native libraries.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ntvinv in java.library.path
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ntvinv in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
atcom.esri.arcgis.system.EngineInitializer.initializeVisualBeans(Unknown Source)
at Interface.SondageOCP.main(SondageOCP.java:282)
at Deploy.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:13)
Exception in thread "ArcGIS VisualBean Mode STA Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLin
kError: com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjRef.runMessagePump()V
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjRef.runMessagePump(Native Method)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Could not load native libraries.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ntvinv in java.library.path
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ntvinv in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjRef.p(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.Dispatch.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.Dispatch.isNativeMode(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.Dispatch.createDispatch(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.Dispatch.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.version.IArcGISVersionProxy.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.version.VersionManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.version.VersionManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.system.EngineInitializer.setVersionAndInitialize(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.system.EngineInitializer.initializeVisualBeans(Unknown Source)
at Interface.SondageOCP.main(SondageOCP.java:282)
at Deploy.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:13)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize native code invocation: null
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjRef.p(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.Dispatch.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.Dispatch.isNativeMode(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.Dispatch.createDispatch(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.Dispatch.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.version.IArcGISVersionProxy.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.version.VersionManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.version.VersionManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.system.EngineInitializer.setVersionAndInitialize(Unknown Source)
at
com.esri.arcgis.system.EngineInitializer.initializeVisualBeans(Unknown Source)
at Interface.SondageOCP.main(SondageOCP.java:282)
at Deploy.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:13)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Can not use native code:
Initialisation failed
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjRef.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.Dispatch.createDispatch(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.Dispatch.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.version.IArcGISVersionProxy.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.version.VersionManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.version.VersionManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.system.EngineInitializer.setVersionAndInitialize(Unkn
own Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.system.EngineInitializer.initializeVisualBeans(Unknow
n Source)
at Interface.SondageOCP.main(SondageOCP.java:282)
at Deploy.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:13)
```

Comment: Can you replace your picture of errors with the same as text so that it is available to future searches, please?  Can you also take the 2-minute [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols, please?

Comment: You've got the question tagged 10.1, but you're following 9.2 documentation?!  The initialization code changed significantly between 10.0 and 10.1 -- You'll need to include the code which produces this result.

Comment: i've not found the bootstrapper class for 10.1 so i used 10.0.

Comment: Mixing "old" sofware with "so old it's been Retired" software is unwise. Please make use of the `{}` formatting button to indent all your code for legibility.

Comment: I've just edited with the 10.1 bootstrap class but still not working

Comment: Still not indented correctly.

Comment: How can i fix this, my question contains the 10.1 bootstrap class

Comment: It looks like the library isn't even being loaded, much less initialized. Have you added the ArcGIS libraries to your PATH?

Comment: If you meant the arcObject yes, actually in eclipse it works very well, but not in the command line

Answer (score -1):

copy from `ArcGIS/desktop/bin` all files  to `jdk/bin`